# How to "publish" a module property in Verilog?

Tags: verilog

Verilog beginner's question: Is there a way a module can publish its static/constant **property** such as width of the address bus slice or number of internal registers? It it not a parameter, rather information inherent to the module being instantiated. Neither it is module *output* data.

Something like the (improper) *.addr( addr[**amod.AMOD_ADDR_W**-1:0] )* below

```
module top_mod #(parameter ADDR_W = 32) 
               (input [ADDR_W-1:0] addr);
    amod amod( .addr( addr[amod.AMOD_ADDR_W-1:0] ) );
endmodule
// ---
module amod( 
    input [AMOD_ADDR_W-1:0] addr
    );
    // AMOD_ADDR_W is amod's intrinsic property
    localparam AMOD_ADDR_W = 2;
endmodule
```

Global defines don't seem the way to go to me.

I'd also appreciate links to some useful Verilog coding hints.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Verilog's elaboration process prevents parameter values from flowing up the hierarchy. In this case, there is no need to match the port width; Verilog will truncate or pad the connection as needed. So there is no need for you to do this.

In SystemVerilog, a `package` is the way to share parameter values between `module`s.

```
package amod_pkg;
  parameter ADDR_W=2;
endpackage
module amod import amod_pkg::*; ( 
    input [ADDR_W-1:0] addr
    );
    // ADDR_W is amod's intrinsic property

endmodule

// ---
module top_mod #(parameter ADDR_W = 32) 
               (input [ADDR_W-1:0] addr);
    amod amod( .addr( addr[amod_pkg::ADDR_W-1:0] ) );
endmodule
```

Comment: Thank you despite the answer is not as encouraging as I hoped :)

Comment: (Oh, timeout on edit :()    While the port width may not be an issue, I'm also interested in a solution of the other example (a number). I wonder how one can `generate` a set of instances of an almost-a-black-box ("tell me how many regs are within to be able to properly decode base addresses") :)

Comment: If you _know_ the name of the module you need to instantiate, then you should _know_ the localparam value inside it. Yes, it makes it harder to maintain, but that's Verilog. Switch to SystemVerilog and use a `package`.